# PHP Imagepng output does not shown in the browser

Tags: php, gd

I spent my last night to solve this problem.

I have a php file which is supposed to return a PNG image with relevant headers. The relevant file content is basically. (No previous output or whitespace before the header statement)

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$img = @imagecreatefrompng($path);

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

But the browser (Firefox) says sth like there is an error with the image, therefore it cannot be displayed.

If I save the file to another place and download it with FTP, it is shown. Like:

```
imagepng($img, "/tmp/hedede.png");
```

If I remove the header statement and printout the file content it shows PNG header with all the other garbage data. If I save this page on browser as a PNG file, browser again does not show the saved PNG file, but Irfanview shows it.

Comment: Remove "@" from imagecreatefrompng, you might have an error there you are missing.

Comment: Yes, you may get some notices like this :'abc' is not a valid PNG file

Comment: I removed the "@" char. But still I didn't get any error even though `error_reporting` was set to `(E_ALL)`. I am also sure that the input file is a valid PNG and I can display it if I directly call that file using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file (in the path) MIME type, don't trust the file type by its extension. Hope it helps. If your file is not a png image, the code does not run properly and doesn't display the given image.

Comment: I am sure that the input file is a valid PNG and I can display it if I directly call that file using a browser.

Comment: haizz, you can not sure it is a valid png or not if you DON'T check its mime type. I can change a abc.gif file to abc.png and view it on a browser.

Comment: thanks, but if I printout file content without any header parameter I can see the file content starting with `‰PNG `. That's why I assume that it was a PNG file. Please let me know how to check mime type if I am not doing it in a right way.

Comment: @noway can you give me your code and your image, I will check it. :)

Comment: @noway and which php version that you used?

Comment: thanks, how can I send you the files? I could not find out a way to reach you even on your blog :)

Comment: @noway I think you can give me a link to download, e.g:mediafire.com.

Answer (score -1):

This is GD Library Version Problems.

```
imagepng($resource)
```

...work old version GD Libray. New Version Would be:

```
imagepng($resource,"php://output")
```

Comment: Wut? Where did you get this from?